# How does the Bukkit plugin "AsyncWorldedit" differ from "SafeEdit"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-worldedit

I am familiar with both the plugins [SafeEdit](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/safeedit/) and [AsyncWorldedit](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/async_worldedit/) and how they operate, I think.

If I understand correctly, SafeEdit pastes in WorldEdit files by doing them chunk-by-chunk, and AsyncWorldedit performs WorldEdit actions by having them be spaced out among each tick per second to reduce lag, to explain them very, very basically.

So, my question is, ***which plugin results in better performance on a server and why?*** I have heard rumors that SafeEdit is a less stable plugin, and that AsyncWorldedit is the more stable option to take. I don't know if this is true or not, but I just wanted to confirm it with hard evidence if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answers which plugin is better, not which performs better -- you'll see why:**

---

## The winner:

AsyncWorldEdit

## The Why:

ASW is easier to use than SafeEdit, since it uses the Worledit API and such the same commands, where as SE uses it's own commands.

This results in the plugin being able to be put in your folder & forgotten about, since you don't need to learn anything new.

## But what about performace?:

From what I've seen, SE is better in performance, but *only on large edits*. Otherwise, they make no difference, and you can configure ASW to work better for your server, possibly eliminating this gap

## Bottom line:

For performance, you want SE. For a better plugin over all, you want ASW

---

Source:
https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/asyncworldedit-v-safeedit-%E2%80%93-which-is-better-and-why.7025/